# I Want to allow users who are logged in to edit their info

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to make the user who are logged in can allow their details i'm am confused as when i use the following code it doesnot allow me to edit a particular user's info
This is my edit.php in this old details of user should be displayed in textboxes but the text boxes are shown empty can anyone fix this

edit.php

```
    <?php 

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','root','root') or die ("Couldn't connect to server.");  
$db = mysql_select_db('test', $connection) or die ("Couldn't select database.");  



$data ="select first_name,last_name,father_name,address,pincode,dob,phone from acc"; 
  $query = mysql_query($data) or die("Couldn't execute query. ". mysql_error()); 
  $data2 = mysql_fetch_array($query); 

?> 

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html> 
<head> 
      <title></title> 
 </head> 

<body> 

<!-- form to display record from database --> 
<center>
<form name="form" method="POST" action="abcd2.php"> 
  first Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $query['first_name']?>"/> <br> 
 last Name : <input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $query['last_name']?>"/> <br>
 father Name: <input type="text" name="fathername" value="<?php echo $query['father_name']?>"/> <br> 
 address: <input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo $query['address']?>"/> <br> 
 pincode: <input type="text" name="pincode" value="<?php echo $query['pincode']?>"/> <br> 
  DOB: <input type="text" name="dob" value="<?php echo $query['dob']?>"/><br>
  phone: <input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $query['phone']?>"/> <br> 
      <input type="submit"  value="submit"> 
</form> 
</center>
</body> 

</html>
```

update.php

```
    <?php 

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','root','root') or die ("Couldn't connect to server.");  
$db = mysql_select_db('test', $connection) or die ("Couldn't select database."); 

$firstname=$_POST['firstname']; 
$lastname=$_POST['lastname']; 
$fathername=$_POST['fathername']; 
$address=$_POST['address']; 
$pincode=$_POST['pincode'];
$dob=$_POST['dob'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];

$data = "UPDATE `acc` SET first_name='$firstname', last_name='$lastname', father_name='$fathername', address='address', pincode='$pincode', dob='$dob', phone='$phone' "; 
  $query = mysql_query($data) or die("Couldn't execute query. ". mysql_error()); 

?> 

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html> 
<head> 
      <title></title> 
 </head> 

<body> 

<!--  display the changed record from database --> 
<center>
  First Name: <?php echo $firstname?><br> 
  Last Name: <?php echo $lastname?><br>
  Father Name: <?php echo $fathername?><br>
  Address: <?php echo $address?> <br> 
  Pincode: <?php echo $pincode?><br>
  DOB: <?php echo $dob?><br>
  Phone: <?php echo $phone?><br><br> 
</center>
</body> 

</html>
```

Comment: Side note, stop using `mysql_*` functions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?s=1|9.6200

Comment: @Rasclatt yeah i know i shouldn't use but i'm stll learning but i'll later change it thanks

Comment: `$query` is the query, `$data2` is the array of data, so `$query['first_name']` etc. is probably `$data2['first_name']` instead.

Comment: use $data2['first_name'] in text boxes.

Comment: @Rasclatt thansk now it displays the details in text boxes !!

Comment: Great! Now that you have it working, you should change `mysql_*` to `PDO`! No sense in doing it wrong right from the start.

Comment: If you have to do it for a particular user don't you think you need to fetch those particular details with his unique id

Comment: @Rasclatt but i have a problem when i insert phone number it takes input but diplayes some other number

Comment: @Rohan yeah how do i fetch user id ?

Comment: Are you using sessions at all or how do you differentiate users?

Comment: You need a `where` clause so you update the right person's data, but you have to be able to know who the user is...

Comment: @Rasclatt  i'm stll not using any session because i dont have knowledge about how to do it thanks

Comment: That is a problem then. You need to use sessions or cookies so you can tell each user apart from one another.

Comment: When you do an update without using a `where`, you are updating every row of your table with the same info.

Comment: You might want to look into using a framework that will do a lot of this stuff for you.

Comment: @Rasclatt i know i should use something like sessions or cookies but i dont know how to do it can you help me

Comment: @Vamshi in the table where you are storing this information don't you have a column that acts as a primary key for the user to show his uniqueness. If you do when you log in put that key in the session variable then when you are fetching the data use that key

Comment: <?php session_start(); this should be at the top to start the session and $_SESSION[‘id'］ = id of the user

Comment: Now when you add this value in the session variable you can start a session on any page and access this value with $_SESSION［'id'］

Comment: @Rohan i use user_id to show uniqness

Comment: @Rohan i have a doubt how does it identify the id from list of ids

Comment: I hope this data fetching is happening on the users end because when a particular user will log in only his id will be in his session.

Comment: @Rohan i did something like this `if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])!="")
{
$data ="select first_name,last_name,father_name,address,pincode,dob,phone from acc"; 
  $query = mysql_query($data) or die("Couldn't execute query. ". mysql_error()); 
  $data2 = mysql_fetch_array($query); 
}`

Comment: In your select query use where clause to compare it with the user id

Comment: @Rohan is it like this `where user_id='($_SESSION['user_id'])' `

Comment: Without the brackets

Comment: Do you want me to post a sample algorithm as the answer. The complete flow from sign up

Comment: @Rohan yeah that would be appriciated

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question and invalidate existing answers. You probably want to read: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/3933332

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample steps 
Sign up : insert into database with the assumption of the id is set as auto increment and primary key.

"Please add start_session() right after you open the PHP tag or a header related error might be thrown."

Log in :

1. Authenticate user 
    If login successful then add id,name,email in session variable

   Else 
   Destroy session
2. User logs in his profile 
   Fetch the data of the user by comparing his user_id from session variable
   e.g. ( select * from tbl where user_id = '$_SESSION［‘id'］')
   Thus you will have the data of the user
3. Update data 
   ( Update tbl set col = value.... where user_id = $_SESSION［‘id'］)

In this way if you follow these steps your insert,update,fetch updated values of particular users is handled. 
Since you have just started using sessions keep in mind that its unique per user so don't worry about the id which is in the variable it will be of the particular user.

Answer (score 1):

Brother, for the sake of least security purpose of the users of your website, please do not implement these codes to edit or update informations. i may tell you some reasons for that.

1. You are using **mysql*** that is the stuff of php4 and you must know that current version is php7 so you are using a really old version.
   You must learn PDO or MySQLi. PDO would be preferable.

   Learning new stuff like MySQLi/PDO is not a rocket science, it will take just couple of days, but the result would be far more better than your current situation.
2. You are using queries like `UPDATE xyz SET x = "123", y="456" WHERE z = "987"` A really novice hacker may retrieve your database information using merely address bar of browser. Precisely learn about special chars escaping like **htmlspecialchars**,or PDO Params for the purpose like `$firstname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstName'])`.
3. For retrieving the data from database for a unique user, preferably use session. `

   Session is nothing but the access data on server for the environment of your website.  Each time you run a login script, then at the line where your code completes all check, use this code:

   ```
   session_start(); 
   $_SESSION['firstname'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstname'])
   // and so on...
   ```

   That is ok. Now in the form where you want to fill the user data, use

   ```
   <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['firstname'];?>">`
   ```